# Check number of digits

Tags: ios, digits

This may be simple answer... What is the quickest algorithm to check if a number contains more than four digits? I am trying to create an if-then statement. If number x contains more than 4 digits, then...

Comment: This may be a simple answer, but the question entirely depends on what kind of object you need to be checked... is it in a NSString, a NSNumber, an integer or long or?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm not sure if this is really as super basic as it sounds or not, but here's a couple of thoughts that might help:

Assuming it's an integer, can you simply test for it being 10,000 or greater (or -10,000 or less)?

```
if (abs(numberToTest) > 9999) {
    // Number has 4 or more digits

} else {
    // Number has 3 or fewer digits
}
```

Alternatively, if you're dealing with decimal values, you could try this:

```
NSString *stringToTest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", numberToTest];

// If you want to exclude the decimal place from the calculation
stringToTest = [stringToTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." 
                                                       withString:@""];

// If you want to include a negative sign from the calculation
stringToTest = [stringToTest stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" 
                                                       withString:@""];
if (stringToTest.length > 4) {
    // String has 5 or more digits

} else {
    // String has 4 or fewer digits

}
```

Anyway, you didn't give a ton of detail, but maybe this solves your problem.

Comment: Wow, that's a way more thorough answer than I was expecting from the question.

Comment: I like to try to get into the head of the OP and answer the question they likely are asking, even if the original question is a bit hazy. Maybe it helps them... maybe it helps someone else...

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I know it was not a very intelligent question...

Comment: @DocBrown With only 10 reputation, I assume you're feeling your way around this site for the first time. Welcome and keep asking! This is a great place to learn. I *would* try to make your questions clearer when you ask them, though. ;-)

Comment: Yes, I am VERY new to Xcode and this site. And I'm having fun. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if its an int you could just subtract the number minus 9999 and determine if the result is negitive or positive but i assume its more complex than this

Comment: If this is the answer, wouldn't a simple `<` or `>` check be better than subtraction, followed by a `<` or `>`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could just use an if statement

if (number > 9999)

print" we are in the 10000 range";

else

print " we are in less than 10000";

Answer (score 0):

Is one line short enough?

```
let moreThanFourDigits = String(yourNumber).count > 4
```

Here I simply transform the number into a string and count the characters.